# Subgroups of $\mathrm{O}_3$ that are the symmetry groups of compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: gr.group-theory, mg.metric-geometry, lie-groups, topological-groups, classical-groups

Is there a classification theorem for the subgroups of $\mathrm{O}_3$ that are the symmetry groups of compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Apparently, there is an almost complete classification [in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_groups_in_three_dimensions). I went through all the footnotes and references I could - there is not even half of what is written on the wiki.

**Edit**: I found a link for a list of all finite symmetry groups. It is easy to analyze each for the existence of a compact that realizes it - the discrete part of my question has been resolved:

> N.W. Johnson: Geometries and Transformations, (2018) ISBN 978-1-107-10340-5 Chapter 11: Finite symmetry groups, Table 11.4 Finite Groups of Isometries in 3-space

The list of groups is nicely presented on [the corresponding wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_spherical_symmetry_groups) (where I found this book).

Comment: These are closed subgroups of $O_3$, and probably most closed subgroups occur this way. Not all of them: $SO_3$ doesn't occur since it has the same orbits as $O_3$. I'm not sure whether it's the only exception.

Comment: This is not the only exception. For example, there is a closed subgroup of rotations around a fixed axis, but any set with such symmetries will also have mirror symmetries.

In fact, there are no exceptions only among discrete subgroups.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed there are four subgroups containing the group $G_d$ of rotations of an axis $d$: $G_d\simeq SO(2)$ itself, the pointwise stabilizer of $d$ ($\simeq O(2)$) which has the same orbits as $G_d$, the whole stabilizer of $d$ ($\simeq O(2)\times O(1)$, which has 4 components), the intersection of the latter with $SO(3)$, and the direct product $SO(2)\times O(1)$ (the latter three also have the same orbits). This completes the picture as regards infinite closed subgroups.

Comment: And OK, I agree that (more generally) a finite subgroup of $GL_n(K)$ is determined by the set of its orbits on $K^n$, if $K$ has char 0. Indeed, let $F,F'$ have the same orbits. Then the subgroup $F''=\langle F,F'\rangle$ also has the same orbits. Since they have bounded size, $F''$ has bounded exponent and hence as a linear group with bounded exponent, it is finite. This boils down to when $F\subset F'$. Let now $x$ be a generic point. Then $x$ is fixed by no element of $F'-\{\mathrm{id}\}$.  So $|F'x|=|F'|$. Since $F'x=Fx$, we deduce $|Fx|=|F'|$, so $|F|\ge |F'|$, hence $F=F'$.

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me, please, why any infinite group contains a group of rotations around some axis?

Comment: @YCor I also think about the following question: is it true that the connected component of the symmetry group of a compact subset $\mathbb{R}^n$ is isomorphic (as a topological group) $SO (k)$ for some $k$? I asked about [this on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4316536/is-the-symmetry-group-of-a-compact-subset-of-mathbbrn-closed). Could you please advise me some literature?

Comment: Modulo this fact, it is clear that the connected component of the identity of the infinite group is either $SO (3)$ or $SO (1)$. In the first case, it seems obvious that then our group is $O (3)$, but how to prove this, I do not understand yet. In the second, it seems that $SO (1)$ should be a group of rotations around some straight line, but why?

Comment: You mean $SO(2)$: $SO(1)$ is the trivial group. The Lie algebra of an infinite closed subgroup is a Lie subalgebra of positive dimension, hence of dimension 1 or 3. If 3, the subgroup is open and hence its unit component is $SO(3)$. Otherwise, its unit component is the stabilizer of an axis, hence a copy of $SO(2)$. Possibly there's a direct proof not using Lie algebras.

Comment: @YCor Yes, I meant SO (2), sorry! (I was sleepy and accidentally wrote the dimensions of these manifolds in parentheses)

Comment: @YCor Hmm, by the way, saying "there are no exceptions only among discrete subgroups" I also thought about the fact that you proved. But does it this imply that any discrete subgroup $O_n$ is the symmetry group of a compact subset?

Comment: A little more argument would be needed, but I think it works. Basically one needs to replace one point by a "small finite affinely independent subset with no symmetry" and take the orbit of this subset.

Comment: @YCor I downloaded all the famous textbooks on Lie group theory - please tell me what to read to learn about facts such as "The Lie algebra of an infinite closed subgroup is a Lie subalgebra of positive dimension, hence of dimension 1 or 3. If 3, the subgroup is open and hence its unit component is $SO (3)$" and further